# Send notification to user even when screen off

Tags: android

My app sends notifications via NotificationManager to the user once every hour. Now it may happen that the screen of the device goes off within that hour, but my notification should still be sent (and ring/vibrate the phone, but not turn on screen). How can I achieve to send a notification even if screen is off (CPU off)? I read about Handler and AlarmManager, but not sure if that's what I need. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` to get control every hour -- whatever you are doing right now is very inefficient.

Specifically, you will need to use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent` and a `_WAKEUP` style alarm. This will wake up the phone and give you control in `onReceive()` of your `BroadcastReceiver`, with the device awake until `onReceive()` returns. There, you raise your `Notification`.